# User does not exist error in chroot

Tags: linux, chroot

I have created a web application where user can run Java code in the browser.

I am using `chroot` for executing user submitted code in the web server.

In the `chroot` script I am doing mounting and then unmounting some required directories.
this works very well normally but when I fire that executing requests in a row like 
20-30 requests, then for some response I am getting this message `/bin/su: user XXX does not exist` where *XXX* is username for the Linux system where I am mounting the required directories.

While for others I am getting the expected output result.

My concern is "is there any side effect of doing `mount` and `unmount` repeatedly in the Linux box?

Or is there any setting in the Linux to make this config to support?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `/bin/su` you need to have the user information provided by `/etc/passwd`.  Have you mounted that directory or (as I would recommend) copied it to the `/etc/` in the new root directory?

Concerning your mount issues, yes, mounting and unmounting can take some time and is not guaranteed to be instantaneous (especially the unmounting can plainly fail if something is still active on the mounted file system).  So maybe you should check if the unmount failed and retry in that case.

Comment: (Dhananjay replied to my answer in an own "answer", so you might want to read that now.)

Comment: I propose to reduce the mount/unmount events drastically by caching them.  I. e. each time you want to mount something, have a look in a cache structure whether this is already mounted, and mount it only if it is not yet.  Unmount things only in case you are running out of mount points (loop devices, etc.) or if the thing hasn't been used for sth like an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply...Yes you are absolutely right Alfe! it is the problem of mounting/unmounting  in a row. I have checked this by SSH login to my web server. when I executed 20-30 program commands repeatedly(separated by semicolon) then I got the desired output in a sequence on my window . then I opened another SSH window and again I executed 10 commands from that window and 20 commands from previous window .  when I saw the output then for some commands in both the windows I got that message of "/bin/bash user XXX doesnt exist". so one conclusion is that when I make web requests concurrently then execution of commands(chroot/unchroot) are not in a sync. that's why I am getting this message. I am not very good in Linux . I don't  know How can I address this issue.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question (which is a pity because the text itself is good and should have been a comment to my answer or, if you prefer that, to your original question).  Other readers having the same or at least a similar issue and who are coming across your question here will have a hard time understanding this if I now reply to your "answer" here, so this messes things up a bit, but nevermind.  See my reply below my answer!